# метод clipPath класса Canvas не обрезает заданный участок

Tags: flutter, dart

Метод clipPath класса Canvas не обрезает заданный участок. Синим цветом нарисован квадрат. Метод clipPath должен обрезать его, что бы получился треугольник. Это не происходит. Подскажите. Далее, полный код и скришот. 
***main.dart***

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
   debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
   title: 'Name App',
   theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
   ),
   home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
     title: Text('Name Page'),
    ),
    body: MyHomePage(),
   ),
  );
 }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

 @override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();

 }

 @override
 void dispose() {
  super.dispose();

 }

 void _f1() {
  setState(() {

  });
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Stack(
   children: [
    Align(
     alignment: Alignment.center,
     child: CustomPaint(
      //верхний слой
      foregroundPainter: A(),
      //средний слой
      child: Container(
       width: 300.0,
       height: 300.0,
       decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(
         width: 1.0,
         color: Colors.pink
        ),
       ),
      ),
     ),
    ),
   ],
  );
 }

}

class A extends CustomPainter {

 @override
 void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {

  //синий цвет, заполнение
  final paint = Paint()
   ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
   ..color = Colors.blue;

  //квадрат
  canvas.drawRRect(
   RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
    Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, 250, 250),
    Radius.circular(0)
   ),
   paint,
  );

  //область треугольника, которая должна обрезаться
  canvas.clipPath(
   Path()
    ..lineTo(0.0, 0.0)
    ..lineTo(0, size.height - 50)
    ..lineTo(size.width - 50, size.height - 50)
    ..close()
  );

 }

 @override
 bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
  return false;
 }

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: сначала __canvas.clipPath__, а потом __canvas.drawRRect__

Comment: @Spatz правильно сказал как решить вашу проблему. Это происходи потому что каждый слой (`canvas.`) накладывается на друг-друга в виде стека.

Comment: Уважаемый Spatz, огромное Вам спасибо. Сделайте из Вашего комментария ответ, что бы его можно было принять и сделать полезным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Работа с *контуром обрезки* в [Canvas](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas-class.html) очень похожа на работу с трафаретом: вы сначала накладываете его а потом рисуете там, где трафарет не закрывает холст. Контуров может быть несколько и результатом будет их *пересечение*.

Вместе с *матрицей преобразования* текущий *контур обрезки* формирует так называемый *контекст* и его можно сохранять и восстанавливать методами [save](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas/save.html) и [restore](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas/restore.html).